# Exclude number in loop

Tags: javascript

I want to exclude some number in the series without conditional statement

Eg:

> exclude number 6 and 9 in the series of number 1 - 10

Something like this:

```
let text = "";
for (let i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i != 6 && i !=9)
        text += i + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: dear a loop has a conditional statement otherwise it will run forever and will not stop. please clarify more what you want and put what you have done so far

Comment: Why dont you want conditional statements?

Comment: A condition is required to check the possibility of the number. 
To be more precise you can write a helper method with javascript and pass it 2 arrays that will filter out the numbers for you.

Comment: and how exactly you want to exclude something without conditional statement...its javascript not some AI that it will read your mind.. If you explain better what exactly you need and what are conditions ..then only user can give solution

Comment: @Martijn my friend ask this question to me, I just curious about it. so i ask this question

Comment: Thank you @ShahzaibShahid no way other than filter by another array

Comment: Sorry @MakSr, but i just want to know the possibility to that or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a valid solution for your issue? Or this conditional statement aren't valid neither

```js
var ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
console.log(ex.filter(function(value, index, arr){
    return value !== 6 && value !== 9;
}));
```

edit, after you've added some code:

```js
let text = "";
const numbers = 10;
const arr = Array.from(Array(numbers).keys());

text = arr.filter((n) => {
  return n !== 9 && n !== 6;
  }).join('<br>'); //@Thomas edit
  
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Edit from @Thomas: changed .toString().replaceAll(',', '
') with .join('
')

Comment: Lafa could you share any reference for understand filter() better

Comment: Sure, this is a very poor impletation for that function, but mozilla did a great job in the explaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=en

The name already say everything

Comment: instead of `.toString().replaceAll(',', '<br>');` just do `.join('<br>');`

Comment: I dont get it you are still using condition yet he is fine with it. maybe its a language barrier and he just means if statement not conditional statement

Comment: Yea @Adam, or he was searching for a different way to do that thing, anyway we found a solution, and he learned something, the objective has been accomplished. Have a good day!

Comment: Yes @Andam he also done things via conditions, but I state here to get rid of the usage of if, else-if, switch statement.

Comment: @LorenzHart ahh, that was not clear from your question. by the way there is also switch case statement. its also a conditional statment if that helps

Answer (score -1):

```
for(let i = 0; i<=10; i ++) {
  i !=6 && i != 9 ? console.log(i): null
}
```